# How do you specify all day events using jQuery addcalevent

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have the jQuery plugin 'addcalevent' installed, the code looks like this:

```
    $(".event").addcalevent({
        'data': {
            "title": "xyz",
            "desc": zyx",
            "location": "xyz",
            "url": "http://www.jqueryscript.net",
            "time": {
                "start": "May 8, 2018 00:00:00",
                "end": "May 8, 2018 24:00:00",
                "zone": "+8:00",
                "allDay": true
            },
        },
        'apps': [0, 1, 2],
        'ics': "myICSfile.ics"
    });
```

The calendar event for Outlook and Yahoo works fine (specifies all day events) but the one for Google shows a time and does not check the 'all day event' input box.

Comment: have you tried `allday:true` as per documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the documentation that you just specify the start and end date like "yyyy-mm-dd" without the time, if it's an all-day event:

> **start.date**  date  The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
>
> **end.date**  date  The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.